# solrj xml output in a file

Tags: xml, solr, solrj

I set up a Solr Server on a TomCat-Servlet. In my Index there are about 610.000 Documents with several fields. My schema.xml:

```
<field name="ID" type="myText" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="text" type="myText" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<dynamicField name="AT*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

To search the Index with a given String (might be from another system) I created a little JavaProgram

```
class SolrjTest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
SolrjTest solrj = new SolrjTest();
solrj.query(args[0]);
}
public void query(String q) throws IOException
{
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = null;
String uuid = null;
boolean flag = true;
while(flag==true)
{   
uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
File f = new File("E:/dw-solr/tomcat-solr/bin/solr/data/SearchResult/"+uuid+".txt");
if(!f.exists()){
flag = false;
}
}
try
{
server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(q);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("E:/dw-solr/tomcat-solr/bin/solr/data/SearchResult/"+uuid+".txt");
try
{
QueryResponse qr = server.query(query);
SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults();

Object[] o = new Object[sdl.size()];
o = sdl.toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
System.out.println(o[i].toString());
fw.write(o[i].toString() + "\n");
}
fw.flush();
fw.close();
System.out.println("finished");
}
catch (SolrServerException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And the results are saved in files. The problem is, that the format of the data is really strange. It looks like:

"SolrDocument[{ID=0000000, AT_anyName=[anyValue, multiValue, justMoreValue], AT_anyName2=[Normal,Normal, Normal], AT_mightbeanothername=[couldbealoooooooooooooooongvalue, andanotherone, andanotherone]muchMoreStuff...about 20 - can differ from ID to ID}]"

What I want to have, is a clear XML-format for this data. So I save it as a XML-file and send it back to the other System. The problem is, that the Method SolrDocumentList sdl = qr.getResults(); return the result as shown above. As I posted before, I have dynamicFields so stuff get really complicated (at least for me :-/ ).
Is there any solution, how I can change the format to a plain, clear XML-format?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Response Writers](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Response+Writers) is used to generate different formats of the search responses.By default it returns the XML response. By sending the HTTP request you can get response in xml format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this line "server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser()); so if I now print out the QueryResponse Object I get the same data like postet in the thread, but just in 1 line...

Comment: @parvin If you use SolrJ the default format is javabin. You can change it through the wt parameter, but the query response already contains java objects obtained from the response itself. I don't think there's an out of the box way to get the raw xml response with SolrJ.

Comment: @javanna I don't mean to send solrj request when I write http request. What i mean here is to sent http request without using solrj.

Comment: I see, I totally agree. I got confused because the question contained code which uses SolrJ.

Comment: It was my fault, I didn´t know what exactly you meant with the http-client. I´m sorry for this. Thanks a lot for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

There IS a way to get a clear XML format from a solrj reply, just using solrj methods. The relevant methods are toXML (to get a String) or writeXML (to write to a file) methods from http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_0_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html

For instance, to just print the XML you could do:

```
    QueryResponse qr = solrclient.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = qr.getResults();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        String xml = ClientUtils.toXML(ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument(results.get(i)));
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
```